# Black 76 for Options on Interest Rate Futures

Tags: options, black-scholes, futures

This is my first time using Black76 to value options on IR futures and I have a question on $F$ and $K$.

I understand the price for an IR future is usually quoted as $100 - r$.  Do I use this price as $F$ in Black76 or do I have to use $r$ and also convert the strike $K$ to an interest rate?

If I have to use interest rates for $F$ and $K$, how should I treat negative rates i.e. strike prices greater than 100?

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up implementing a different model for -ve rates.  I've used Bachelier's (Guassian) model that allows negative values.  Most of the IR futures options are short-dated so model differences are within my tolerance.